# JavaFX animation does not work in a Stack Pane

Tags: java, javafx, computer-science

I am working on a class assignment, a pong game. 
Below is the requirement.

A rectangular paddle moves back and forth via mouse drag along the bottom of the pane;
If the ball connects with the paddle, then it bounces at a 90-degree angle back into the pane space;

The mouse and keyboard actions do not work properly, no response to mouse and keys.

I can't figure out the problem. Any helps will be really appreciated.

PongForOne.java

```
public class PongForOne extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BallPane ball = new BallPane();
        PaddlePane paddle = new PaddlePane();
        StackPane stkPane = new StackPane();

        stkPane.getChildren().addAll(paddle,ball);

        paddle.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            PaddlePane.paddle.setX(e.getX());
        });

        paddle.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch(e.getCode()){
                case LEFT:  PaddlePane.paddle.setX(PaddlePane.paddle.getX() - 10);  break;
                case RIGHT: PaddlePane.paddle.setX(PaddlePane.paddle.getX() + 10);  break;
                default: break;
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(stkPane, 300, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        ball.requestFocus();
        paddle.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

BallPane.java

```
public class BallPane extends Pane {
    private final double radius = 20;
    private double x = radius, y = radius;
    private double dx = 1, dy = 1;
    private int numBallHitsPaddle = 0;
    private int numBallMissPaddle = 0;
    private final Circle circle = new Circle(x,y, radius);
    private final Text text= new Text (x, y, Integer.toString(numBallHitsPaddle));
    private final Timeline animation;

    public BallPane(){
        circle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        getChildren().addAll(circle, text);
        animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(5), e -> moveBall()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play();
    }
    public void play(){
        animation.play();
    }
    public void pause(){
        animation.pause();
    }
    public void increaseSpeed(){
        animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 0.1);
    }
    public void decreaseSpeed(){
        animation.setRate(
            animation.getRate() > 0 ? animation.getRate() - 0.1 : 0);
    }
    public void colorChange(){
        circle.setFill(Color.color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()));
    }
    public DoubleProperty rateProperty(){
        return animation.rateProperty();
    }
    public boolean ballHitsPaddle(){
        boolean status = false;
        if (x + radius > PaddlePane.getPaddleX() && x - radius < PaddlePane.getPaddleX() + PaddlePane.getPaddleWidth() && y + radius == PaddlePane.getPaddleY()){
             status = true;
        }
        return status;
    }
    /**
     * defines ball's movement
     * changes color every time when ball hits paddle and counts the number of hit
     */
    public void moveBall(){
        if (x < radius || x > getWidth() - radius){
            dx *= -1;
        } 
        if ( y > getHeight() - radius){
            x = getWidth() / 2;
            y = 50;
            dx *= -1;
            numBallMissPaddle++;
        }
        if (y < radius || ballHitsPaddle()){
            if(ballHitsPaddle()) {
                text.setText(Integer.toString(++numBallHitsPaddle));
                colorChange();
            }
            dy *= -1; 
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        circle.setCenterX(x);
        circle.setCenterY(y);
        text.setX(x - 4);
        text.setY(y + 3);
    }   
}
```

PaddlePane.java

```
public class PaddlePane extends Pane{
    private static final double width = 40, hight = 5;
    public static Rectangle paddle = new Rectangle(width, hight);


    public PaddlePane(){
        paddle.xProperty().bind(widthProperty().divide(2).subtract(width / 2));
        paddle.yProperty().bind(heightProperty().subtract(100));
        getChildren().add(paddle);
    }
    public static double getPaddleX(){
        return paddle.getX();
    }
    public static double getPaddleY(){
        return paddle.getY();
    }
    public static double getPaddleWidth(){
        return paddle.getWidth();
    }
    public static double getPaddleHeight(){
        return paddle.getHeight();
    }
    public void colorChange(){
        paddle.setFill(Color.color(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `StackPane`. Use `Pane`.

Comment: Using a stackpane for this kind of game isn't really that advisable, stackpane stretches UI control to fill up the entire scene, you might need to try using other UI layouts like Pane or even AnchorPane might do the trick

Comment: @Sedrick Thanks for the reply. I tried `Pane`, but only ball shows on the window and it moves, more like shakes, in a small range.

Comment: @TuleSimon Thanks for the reply. In `Pane` the ball only moves in a small range instead of the whole window, and paddle disappeared. Could you please tell me the possible reason?

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/PongFX